# Getting first Layer of Room Boundary

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have a problem when getting the first layer of a room boundary segment:
My Revit-Addin gets a selected room and needs to change the "inside" layer of the walls.
Is there a way to get this layer?

[image]

So far I've managed to get the boundary segments of the selected room and get their layers, orientation and position. There is a way to calculate this with the room faces and the wall parameters listed above, but I just wanted to make sure there isn't a simpler way, before I start my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [wall type](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/aa685433-b426-5e4f-bee1-e3487bb59518.htm) [compound structure](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/dc1a081e-8dab-565f-145d-a429098d353c.htm)? I see a [ShellLayerType enumeration](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/75c640b9-9904-7882-43fc-a4dfc25ff53c.htm) that might come in useful...

Comment: I've found this function ([link](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/68e04211-03ea-f0c6-50d5-b38fee4e7536.htm)) which uses the ShellLayerType enum. It seems this function only return information about the CompoundStructure itself, and not in reference to a room.

Comment: For Example: I have two rooms that are separated by Wall A (3 CompoundLayers: Material A, Material B, Material C). Room 1 "touches" Material A and Room 2 "touches" Material C, with Material B being the core layer. If Room 1 is selected I should get Material A and if Room 2 is selected Material C.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```cs
SpatialElementBoundaryOptions boundaryOptions = new SpatialElementBoundaryOptions();
boundaryOptions.SpatialElementBoundaryLocation = SpatialElementBoundaryLocation.Finish;
IList<IList<BoundarySegment>> wallBoundrySegment = room.GetBoundarySegments(boundaryOptions);
```